# How to make my .bat script to run every 5 minutes?

Tags: batch-file

how can I make my .bat script to run every 5 minutes
ok so this is what I'm doing

```
@echo off 
:loop
taskkill /im "task.exe" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /f >nul && start "" "task.exe"
goto loop
```

but now it is running all the time making using task.exe impossible,
so I will like to get it to run every whatever interval so I can use the task as well,
Thanks for your help

Comment: add a new task to the task scheduler

Comment: You could add a `timeout 300` into the loop, but a scheduled task is surely to prefer.

Comment: Not responding menas that your task is already started, but not stopped. Would you not therefore have to stop it, before trying to start it again? Also, if you have a process which is hanging enough for you to need such a thing, you should try to find a fix for that process instead of just constantly having to restart it.

Answer (score 2):

```
schtasks /create /sc MINUTE /mo 5 /tn "MyBat" /tr "C:\MyBat.bat"
```

more about [SCHTASKS](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: well i did use schtasks but that just got my computer to hang opening lot's of running process that at the end used up all my 32 gig of ram and made my computer unusable

Comment: @RalphNaim -what is your bat doing? May be it can be optimised? is it exiting properly - may be there's a `pause` at the end? Is it starting too consumning process? How much time it takes to exit?